# How to speed up the operation of quad integation method applied on a large numpy array to be plotted by matplotlib?

Tags: arrays, function, matplotlib, tuples, integral

I have a function of many constant parameters but only one independent variable *m*. This independent variable runs from some minimum value, *low*, to some maximum value, *up*. These bounds are knowns a priori. Now I would like to define a separate function which calculates the area under the first function in 10 bins of *m*. In effect, I have to integrate the first function at any one of these 10 bins and then store the result in a different array which later needs to be plotted against the independent variable *m*. I have put the left-hand side of my x-values into one array and the right-hand side of my x-values into another array so that these two will be input of the function to be plotted, namely the lower and upper bounds of the integral of the first function. Here is my code to do this in python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad, dblquad
import mpmath as mp


low, up  = 5.630e5, 1.167e12
alpha, xo = 1.05   , 2.15e10     
beta = 274


def g(x, low, up, beta):
    return mp.gamma(-2/3) * (mp.gammainc(-2/3, beta*(x/low)**3) - mp.gammainc(-2/3, beta*(x/up)**3))
gv = np.vectorize(g)

def Integrand1(x, low, up, xo, alpha, beta):
    return pow(x/xo, alpha) * g(x, low, up, beta)

def Integrand2(x, low, up, xo, alpha, beta):
    return g(x, low, up, beta)


def PDF(x, low, up, xo, alpha, beta):
    Integral1 = quad(Integrand1, low, xo, args=(low, up, xo, alpha, beta))
    Integral2 = quad(Integrand2, xo, up, args=(low, up, xo, alpha, beta))
    A=(Integral1[0]+Integral2[0])**(-1)
    y = np.piecewise(x, 
                    [x < xo], [lambda x: A * pow(x/xo, alpha) * gv(x, low, up, beta), 
                                   lambda x: A * gv(x, low, up, beta)
                                  ]
                    )
    return y



x_array = np.array(np.logspace(8.2, 11.8, 10))
deltam = 0.4
lolims, uplims = np.array(np.logspace(8.2-deltam/2, 11.8-deltam/2, len(x_array))), np.array(np.logspace(8.2+deltam/2, 11.8+deltam/2, len(x_array)))


def myfunc(M1, M2, low, up, xo, alpha, beta):
    return np.array([quad(PDF, M1, M2, args=(low, up, xo, alpha, beta)) for M1 in lolims for M2 in uplims])


y_array = np.array([myfunc(M1, M2, low, up, xo, alpha, beta) for M1 in lolims for M2 in uplims]) 
plt.plot(x_array, y_array, color='green', linestyle='-')
plt.gca().autoscale(False)
plt.vlines([xo], linestyles='dashed', color='k', label='')

plt.legend(loc='upper left', ncol=1, fontsize=12)
plt.xlim([1e8, M_max])
plt.ylim([2e-6, 2e-1])
plt.ylabel('x', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('y', fontsize=12)
plt.xscale("log", nonposx='clip')
plt.yscale("log", nonposy='clip')
plt.show()
```

The problem is that the code is running forever. I am not sure if it's correct but not clean and concise or something serious is wrong with it that is not producing the expected plot.

Comment: Have you tried using a profiler such as runsnakerun checking which function calls actually are costly?

Comment: I am not aware of the profiler. But after printing some results at different spots of the code, I believe the last function (*myfunc*) which is actually calculating the area under function *PDF* is taking long especially when two bounds (*low* and *up*) are located on different sides of *x=xo* (*low < xo* and *up > xo*). But this only happens once even though it takes very long time. Part of the delay is also coming from the fact that I need at least 10 bins (to see how the general trend looks like) or ~100 bins to pinpoint the exact pattern (if there is any feature in it). Thanks again,

Comment: sorry I meant *M1* and *M2* rather than *low* and *up* (which are fixed).

Answer (score 0):

Since the output of a `quad` function is a tuple whose first element is the result and second element the error in the result, one must keep only the first elements and work with those as a `numpy` array. However, the bottleneck of the problem is in the way `myfunc` was defined. This function is supposed to take its *M1* variable from *lower limits* and its *M2* variable from *upper limits* arrays. However, the way it is written is not clear as to which order these assignments happen meaning they are getting mixed between two arrays to an extent that causes confusion for the code to know which elements exactly it's supposed to take for (*M1*, *M2*) tuple.

**Partial Answer:**

Use `zip` function to put your range of *M1* and *M2* in an ordered fashion so that *myfunc* would know in each loop what should be taking as its inputs. To do this, one needs to change the definition of *myfunc* and the following *y_array* to the following statements:

```
y_tuples = [quad(PDF, M1, M2, args=(low, up, xo, alpha, beta)) for (M1, M2) in zip(lolims, uplims)]
y_array = np.array([i[0] for i in y_tuples])
```

With this, the issue with the code is resolved but the problem of it being **slow** is *still persistent* and waiting for an answer.